# Do Inline elements establish a Line Box for their content?

Tags: css

W3 is very ambiguous about this. I've read everything about Inline-boxes, Line-boxes, anonymous boxes, block-boxes and all kinds of boxes, but nowhere is explicitly stated whether line boxes are formed inside inline-level elements.

W3 states that

> "line box is the rectangular area that contains the (inline)boxes that
> form a line".

Then it says that

> "Line boxes are created as needed to hold inline-level content within
> an inline formatting context"

So far, it seems that inline elements do contain line boxes, as they can contain inline-boxes, and their content participates in an inline formatting context.

However then it states that

> Any text that is directly contained inside a block container element
> (not inside an inline element) must be treated as an anonymous inline
> element.

So, therefore, the text inside an inline-level element like `span` is not being wrapped inside an anonymous inline box.

Then they give the example of `<P>Several <EM>emphasized words</EM> appear <STRONG>in this</STRONG> sentence, dear.</P>` and explain that

> The P element generates a block box that contains five inline boxes,
> three of which are anonymous. To format the paragraph, the user agent
> flows the five boxes into line boxes. In this example, the box
> generated for the P element establishes the containing block for the
> line boxes. If the containing block is sufficiently wide, all the
> inline boxes will fit into a single line box. If not, the inline boxes
> will be split up and distributed across several line boxes.

This explanation is confusing because the first sentence states that P generates a block-box that contains the inline-boxes, but the second sentence states that the containing block generated by the P element contains the line boxes.

Block box is a block container that is also a block-level box. So, inline-elements don't generate block boxes, but apparently they generate containing blocks. Are block-boxes and containing blocks the same thing in this context?

Since an inline-level box, like `Span` can contain other inline-boxes, like `strong` or `em`, that means that inline-level elements can also be block containers, but they don't form block boxes (or do they?), and their text content does not get wrapped inside an anonymous box.

It is stated that the Inline-boxes do have a containing block, but it is also explicitly stated that the line-boxes are contained inside the block-box, not the containing block.

So, are they the same? .. and does that mean that inline-level boxes like `span` also form a line box? If so, why doesn't the text inside inline-boxes get wrapped inside an anonymous inline box?

If line boxes only exist inside the block box, and if containing blocks are not block boxes, then that would mean that inline elements do not form line boxes for their content.

I wish W3 would be more explicit with their explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your heading and first paragraph ask two different questions:

- Do Inline elements establish a Line Box for their content?
- [Are] line boxes are formed inside inline-level elements?

They have different answers, "No", and "Sometimes" respectively, so the first thing that needs to be dealt with is the `-level` suffix.

An inline-level box is a broader category than an inline box. A span element which contains only text generates, by default, a sequence of inline boxes sufficient to lay out that text content over as many lines as is necessary. **All inline boxes are also inline-level boxes, but the opposite is not true**. Elements whose computed display is `inline-block`, `inline-table`, `inline-flex` and `inline-grid` all generate boxes that are inline-level, but are not inline boxes.

Similar applies to block versus block-level. Block-level describes how a box lays out relative to its **parents and siblings**. Block containers are boxes in which their **child boxes** are laid out either as sequence of block-level boxes, or within a stack of line boxes, and never as a mixture of both.

Elements whose computed display value is `block`, `flow-root` and `list-item` and are being laid out in a block formatting context (i.e. they're not a flex item or a grid item) generate a single box that is both block-level and a block container. These are called block boxes.

But boxes generated for elements that have computed display values of `table`, `flex`, and `grid` are block-level, but they are not block containers. Their descendants are laid out using different rules. These are not block boxes.

Conversely, elements that have computed display values of `inline-block` and `table-cell` generate boxes that are block containers but they are not block-level. They interact with their parents and siblings differently than block level boxes do.

So, specifically, `inline-block` boxes, which are inline-level, contain either a sequence of block-level boxes, or a stack of line boxes in which other inline-level boxes are laid out.

---

Now, an inline box can contain other inline-level boxes, but that does not make it a block container, even if one of those inline-level boxes is itself a block container. The block container of the inline box and all its descendant inline-level boxes that are not themselves inside other formatting contexts is the nearest ancestor that *is* a block container.

So, suppose we have this tree of boxes

```
 display:block                     block level, block container
   |                                                     ↑   ↑ 
   + - display:inline              inline level ---------+   |    \  
         |                                                   |     |- In the same line box
         + - display:inline-block  inline level, block container  /
               |                                          ↑
               + some text         anonymous inline box --+       in a line box
```

where the arrows point from inline-level boxes to their block container.

Comment: so a span element even with only one word inside (to make sure it will always be inside one line) will create another box inside it called *inline box* to contain the text? The span itself won't be that *inline box*?

Comment: @TemaniAfif - Not sure quite what you mean. An element is not a box. A display:inline element containing just text short enough to fit inside a single line box generates just one inline box, not two. Only text nodes whose parent element generates a block container box will generate an anonymous inline box.

Comment: You're saying that the text inside inline boxes don't get wrapped inside an anonymous inline box because inline boxes are not block containers. First of all, why are inline boxes not block containers? Block container means box that either contains only block-level boxes or inline-level boxes. Well, a span can contain only inline-level boxes, so why is that not making it a block container? Also, you didn't answer my question about line boxes and containing blocks. Are containing blocks & block boxes the same in this context? Do inline-level boxes establish line box for their content?

Comment: @Alohci You're saying that inline-level element that contains only text generates a line-box to contain that text? So, you are saying that inline boxes DO form a line-box for their content, be it only text nodes or inline-boxes? So, what is the role of the containing block inside an inline box then? Is it again that, assuming an inline element has only text, that text doesn't get wrapped inside anonymous inline box, but it gets flowed inside a line-box, which gets contained inside a containing block, which is inside the inline box parent? ....

Comment: ... Or is it that, by 'containing block' they mean the content-box of the inline-element? Or is the content-box of the inline-element the line-box? if so, what is the containing box then?

Comment: "Block container means box that either contains only block-level boxes or inline-level boxes". No, not "means".  A block container is a member of the set of possible containers of those two things, but that set can have other members. "Are containing blocks & block boxes the same in this context?" - No. "Do inline-level boxes establish line box for their content?" Inline-block boxes, which are one type of inline-level box establish line boxes for their content. Inline boxes, which are a different type of inline-level boxes, do not.

Comment: ... But, the number of line boxes formed within a block container is determined by the amount of inline content that the block container contains. If the block container contains no inline content, it will form zero line boxes.

Comment: A "containing block" for in-flow content is the content-box of the block container of that content.

Comment: I am also not quite sure what I meant :) I was a bit confused by *A span element which contains only text generates, by default, a sequence of inline boxes sufficient to lay out that text content over as many lines as is necessary.*. I am trying to imagine how the sequence of inline boxes is generated. I have to take more time to read the answer again and again to understand it fully ;)

Comment: @Temani Afif: Consider <p><span>Hello world</span></p> with white-space: normal. Given enough horizontal space, the span will generate a single inline box with the text "Hello world", and reside on a single line box within the p. But if there's not enough horizontal space, the words "Hello" and "world" are split at the whitespace into two "separate" fragments, each on their own line box, both within the p. These fragments are split from a single inline box and you can see this if you add a border.

Comment: @BoltClock the word *generate* means that the span will be the inline box you are talking about or it will generate inside it an inline box to end with a span having inside it an inline box?

Comment: @TemaniAfif - an "inline box" means exactly that, a box that's inside a single line. So you can't have an inline box that contains two inline boxes which are on separate lines within the same inline formatting context. So the span generates just the two inline boxes, one for "Hello" and one for "world".

Comment: @Alohci Sorry I didn't respond yesterday. I never got any notification of your reply. I am just seeing it now for the first time. I wanna take my time and read your replies tomorrow with fresh mind and try to see if I understand it then. I've spent all day today going through the mechanics of HTML again. I've read a lot of about HTML nodes, objects, elements, the box model, outer & inner display type etc, and I've been trying to piece it all together. It is starting to make a bit more sense now, but some of the things are still a bit foggy in my mind. I'll talk to you again tomorrow.

Comment: @Alohci Hi. So, I think have only few question left. It's about the Line-height on inline-elements. Since Inline-boxes don't have a line-box, why is it that, when i apply the line-height to an inline-box, there seems to be some box that is getting enlarged and starts pushing sibling boxes. If there is no line-box, what is happening here? The MDN says that the line-height applied to inline-elements specifies the height that is used to calculate line box height. I can't understand what exactly is that mean. Also, when applied to block container, does it expand the content area? And on that note,

Comment: as I quoted in my original question, a block-level element like P generates a block-box, which then contains a line-box containing the inline-boxes or the text nodes. My question is, is that block-box the principle box of the P element itself, or is that a box generated after the principle-box, and after the containing-block? And if it is, is that block-box part of the content area, and why is it generated in the first place?

Comment: @Ihatecontrolfreaks - Suppose the block container contains only inline boxes (i.e. no other inline-level boxes to complicate things). Then the height of each line box in the block container is determined as being the highest edge of top half-leading (which is determined by each inline box's line-height) of all the inline boxes in the line box, and the lowest bottom half-leading of all those same inline boxes, after those inline boxes have been vertically aligned.

Comment: The P element, when it's `display:block` generates just one block box, i.e. its principal box. The order in which a box and its containing block a generated isn't specified. "part of" isn't the right notion. The box is *laid-out* oriented to its containing block. I don't understand what you mean by "why is it generated?"

Comment: @Ihatecontrolfreaks - On further reflection, maybe the name "line-height" is misleading you when applied to `display:inline` elements. It means that its box makes a contribution to determining the line-height of the line-box *in which it is laid out*, not that applies to a line box that it contains. The opposite is true of the boxes generated for `display:inline-block` elements.

Comment: @Alohci What confuses me is that, suppose you have one block-level element and one span in the body. Now, if you apply line-height 50px to the span, something starts pushing the span down from the edge of the block-element sibling. What is pushing it down? Is it the expansion of the line-box? The body will still form a line-box for the span, right? So does increasing the line-height of the span increase the line-box height, and is that what's pushing the element down? I suppose it's a bit hard to understand since vertical dimensions are not respected, and the content area doesn't expand.

Comment: Is what's pushing the element down the so called imaginary box called "strut"?

Comment: @Ihatecontrolfreaks - The span vertically aligns with the strut. if you apply line-height 50px to the span, then it's the upper half-leading of the span that pushes the span's box down. if you apply line-height 50px to the *body*, then it's the upper half-leading of the strut that pushes the span's box down, because its baseline has to stay vertically aligned with the strut's baseline.

Comment: The line box will entirely contain the full upper and lower half-leadings of both the strut and the span.

Comment: I think I understand now. Is it correct to say that, the min height of a line-box containing a span is determined by the height of the strut, which is based on the line-height of the block container, but the max height of the line-box is based on the line-height of the span? I've just tested it & it works the way I see it. Increasing the line-height of a span increases the height that is used to calculate the height of the line-box, so the line-box enlarges & pushes the span down. Increasing line-height on block container increases the strut inside line-box thus enlarging it again. Right?

Comment: @Ihatecontrolfreaks - Mostly right yes. "... max height of the line-box is based on the line-height of the span". Not sure what you mean by that. The line box grows just sufficiently to contain the line heights of the strut and the span. Since the strut is always present in every line box, the line box height must be at least that tall. If it needs to increase height to include the span it will do so.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant to say. Thanks for all your answers. Happy holidays.

Comment: @Alohci: An inline box isn't "a box that's inside a single line". The parts of an inline box that are split across multiple lines still form one principal inline box. This is called fragmentation and is codified post-CSS2 in css-break-3. An inline element does not generate more than one box unless it's an inline list-item or some other type that's specifically designed to generate more than one box.

Comment: @BoltClock - Noted. Thanks.

Comment: Following through this high quality answer and discussion (which I think deserve much much more votes), I initially thought I understood how inline box works. But after reading @BoltClock's last comment about fragmentation, I am confused again. So an inline box is not necessarily a rectangular area (e.g. when fragmented)?

Comment: @wlnirvana It seems so. css-break-3 does indeed comment that "Breaking inline content into lines ... creates box fragments when it breaks inline boxes across line boxes.". However, it then just references CSS2 and CSS Text Level 3, in neither of which can I find any more details about inline-box fragmentation.

Comment: @wlnirvana: Correct. Unfortunately CSS2 doesn't provide any details, so you'll just have to take its word for it. If it's any consolation, the inline box still appears like a box, only sliced up so borders and padding (and, IIRC, margins) aren't rendered where it's sliced.