# What does it mean that an inline-block is internally formatted as a block box?

Tags: html, css

In the CSS specifications in part 9.2.4 the description of the inline-block value for the display property says:

> This value causes an element to generate a principal inline-level
> block container. (The inside of an inline-block is formatted as a
> block box, and the element itself is formatted as an atomic
> inline-level box.)

What does the following sentence mean?

> The inside of an inline-block is formatted as a
> block box

Does it mean that an inline-block has a block box inside?

Comment: basicly it means it can be sized and apply vertical padding/margin too. it is a boxe standing on the baseline (like img) and takes the size from its content if not set . there is also : table/inline-table, flex / inline-flex and grid / inline-grid

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65191885/8620333